# How to write a makefile with multiple targets and multiple sources?

Tags: linux, variables, makefile

I'm learning how to write makefiles and would like to create a makefile that can create multiple targets from multiple sources according to a given argument.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
# Compiler and others
CC=gcc

# Flags
CFLAGS = -g -c -Wall -DLOGFILE -D_REENTRANT

target1_EXEC = ../build/target1
target2_EXEC = ../build/target2

target1_SRC = ../source/target1
target2_SRC = ../source/target2

target1: TARGET=target1
target1: all

target2: TARGET=target2
target2: all

EXEC=$($(TARGET)_EXEC)
SRC=$($(TARGET)_SRC)
OBJ=$(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

I would like to call the makefile with the target as an argument:

```
makefile target1
```

But then it seems that it does not find the subtarget:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'target1'.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think your second target rules (e.g. `target1: all`) only are executed. Hence, `TARGET` is never given a value and is latter read as an empty string. You might want to use double colons: `target1:: TARGET=target1`, `target1:: all`.